# UnboundLocalError when using str() in python

Tags: python, string

I experience a strange issue!

In my python code I have the following line:

```
tmpstr = str(tx_execution)
listOfSteps[i] += ' AvgTime:' + tmpstr + 'sec.;'
```

But on execution i got:

```
File "/storage/share/test_main.py", line xxxx, in runStep
    tmpstr = str(tx_execution)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'str' referenced before assignment
```

Any clue what could cause this?

I am using in other parts of my python code the command str(), which is working fine!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to assign to `str` later in your function - look for a line like `str = ...` and change the variable name to a more sensible one.

Comment: During trying (since it don't use str as a var name), I found out that the problem is the line with the `listOfSteps[i] +=...` as soon i changed it to `listOfSteps[i] = listOfSteps[i] +...` str() it works fine! Thanks Zero Piraeus again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is:
to change the line `listOfSteps[i] += ...` to:

```
listOfSteps[i] = listOfSteps[i] + ' AvgTime:' + tmpstr + 'sec.;'
```